# Downloading You tube videos?

Tags: java, video, download, youtube

I want to download you tube videos programatically (using Java). How can i convert you tube video link to a downloadable URL.

Browser plays youtube videos with following code.

I tried downloading from URL http://www.youtube.com/v/OdAE3cWlmHw
but it is not returning video bytes.

Thanks 
Lalit

Comment: The video that is returned is in Flash Video (FLV) format.

Comment: If one of A's was good for you, could you accept it? Q is still open.

Answer (score 4):

Youtube API allows you to search & list videos and obtain the mediaplayer URL, so that you can play videos within your web page

[Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api)

[Youtube Java Data API - Search and List Videos](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t103917.html)

[Youtube Java Data API - Getting Started](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html)

It does not allow you to download the byte content of videos - because Google is protecting their own rights and the rights of the content creators.

> **[Google API Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms)
>
>     Prohibitions:**
>
> *Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create
>   functionality for Your users or other third parties to:*
>       ...
>
> - *promote separately the audio or video components of any YouTube audiovisual content made available through the YouTube API*;
> - *access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly
>     authorized by YouTube;*
> - *store copies of YouTube audiovisual content;*
>     ...

Comment: Can we extract the audio only from these videos?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the dosens of extension for Firefox about downloading Flash video's.
Downloadhelper and Flash Video Helper. If you look in the source you will find how to download the video.
From what i remember is that it parses the HTML page for an id and session and use that in an url to download the video.

Similar question found only in C#. Watch the sources and you can recreate it in java
[C#: Downloading video from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/c-downloading-video-from-youtube)

Comment: These tools saves played videos from browser's cache. I do not want to play video in browser. 

I want to create a java program which should be able to download video using URL.

Comment: That's incorrect. For downloadhelper: look at dhYoutubeProbe.js function YTProbe.prototype.handleDocument=function(document,window). There you can see it uses regex to extract video_id and token and use that "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id="+videoId+"&t="+t;"

Comment: Yes we can create a link to download a youtube video. 

But still a problem.

Here is the link to get a you tube video
http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=videoId &t=token;

VideoId is simple we can get it from url.

But what about token. You tube provides a seperate token on each request. Means if i have requested a video from browser. In response my browser will get a token. By using that token i can make a downloadable link and download video using Java program.

But what if i want to download using a program?  From where i will get this token?

Comment: Download first the website and parse it, and use the token from there to start a download. Downloading and parsing the HTML page is quickly done.

Comment: Now i can successfully create downloadable link for video (using token and vidoeId ). I can successfully download video by submitting this URL to browser. I have written a java program that download file from this URL using HttpURLConnection . It downloads file successfully on disk but problem is that i am not able to play this file. An error message is displaying 'This file contains no playable streams'

Comment: Have you got the correct codecs installed? try k-lite codec pack and play with media player classic

Comment: Can someone summarise the complete process for downloading youtube video programatically based on this discussion?

Answer (score -1):

this site has something.. for your need!

http://mashable.com/2009/02/13/youtube-toolbox/