# Download file from indirect URLs

Tags: java, download

I am developing a Java program that downloads a file from given URL. It works perfectly for direct links, eg:

```
http://cdn.muvee.com/downloads/muveeRevealX_10.5.0.23245_2760.exe?AWSAccessKeyId=1026JPYBE0QTTK67WVG2&Expires=1363299511&Signature=ROKk0Jav1Jw5HGU4fcBs6ADhPqI%3D&Extension=.exe
```

But not for indirect links, eg:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BvmqPymyfY&list=PL6EE0CD02910E57B8
```

Output of the program for the Youtube link is:-

```
Fri Mar 15 16:30:48 IST 2013
Content-Type = text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition = null
Content-Length = -1
fileName = watch?v=8BvmqPymyfY&list=PL6EE0CD02910E57B8
java.io.FileNotFoundException: E:\watch?v=8BvmqPymyfY&list=PL6EE0CD02910E57B8 (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:104)
    at HttpDownloadUtility.downloadFile(HttpDownloadUtility.java:62)
    at HttpDownloader.main(HttpDownloader.java:14)
```

Code for HttpDownloadUtility.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpDownloadUtility {

    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        httpConn.connect();
        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }

            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

MAIN FILE: HttpDownload.java:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class HttpDownloader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileURL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BvmqPymyfY&list=PL6EE0CD02910E57B8";
        String saveDir = "E:/";
        try {
            System.out.println(new Date().toString());

            HttpDownloadUtility.downloadFile(fileURL, saveDir);
            System.out.println(new Date().toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but your YouTube link is not a file .

Comment: please help me tht how can i download from any indirect file @ShivanRaptor

Comment: @Akki check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498359/downloading-you-tube-videos) link...

Comment: @PermGenError sorry for it frnd... but it's too urgent for me...beg my pardon

Comment: @HemChe i dont want to use "YouTube API"... i want to make universal program for any of the indirect links.

Comment: @AkkiZaveri CHeck [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5238175/how-can-i-use-java-to-download-a-video-file-from-http-urlvideo-streaming-link) link...

Comment: I've cleaned your link includes. Please never directly hyperlink to executable code, some would see that as an attempt to spread a virus.

Comment: Do you really need to create your tool for this? There are really good programs that can do that for you like http://jdownloader.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply download the files in youtube. When you look into the URLs you used, you can see that the url for which it worked ends with file extension, ie they are direct link, the url is pointing directly towards the file.
If you have to download it from indirect link, example youtube, you have to get the content first and then only you can save it. In youtube, flash players are directly getting the videostream, as i know.

Comment: how can i get the contents from indirect link in java ? that's what i want.

Comment: By indirect link, it mean that the link directs to a html page, where the source is mentioned. So it you want to get that, simply get it from the source code of the page. It will work only with some pages.

Comment: as long as the page provides a correct file download header, the file can be downloaded.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: that will provide a direct link, which it points to the actual file, isn't?

Comment: no. An indirect link still can provide a valid download header, e.g. a PHP file can be an indirect link for image .

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, so, the thing is that, you need to add the extension to the video, for:

```
downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
```

i overwrite it as

```
downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir, String name)
```

then on the

```
// extracts file name from header field
                ......
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
```

replace to

```
String fileName =name+".mp4";
```

BUT it only works with a specific server, i have had download from .com server but a youtube.com or *.in CAN`T works

try it that way